# Vanity search: links to my website posted by other people during last 2 months

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

New query on Data Explorer:

- [**Vanity search: links to my website posted by other people during last 2 months**](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1181)

How it works now:

1. Takes the website that you provided in your user info
2. Strips the possible `http://` prefix
3. Strips the possible trailing `/`
4. Searched comments and posts updated in last two months (since the `DE` engine does not support fulltext indexing, searching the whole corpus results in query timeout)

I tested it on me and Jeff Atwood.

Please test and post the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Very nice.  I had to go back 3 months (I guess I'm 50% more vain than you?) but it seems to work.

[No idea how to solve this SICP exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365993) - 2010-03-02 07:59:29

I also guess I need to post more relevant content on my blog.